# Error in reading Excel file from system?

Tags: python

```
 import xlrd
 book = xlrd.open_workbook("File_1.xls")
 sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
 print sheet.row_values(0)[0]
```

I am trying to read the excel file stored in the system(desktop)the concerned excel sheet has only one sheet, when I ran the code its giving an error :-

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Python26/readingExlfiles.py", line 2, in <module>
 book = xlrd.open_workbook("File_1.xls")
 File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 449, in open_workbook
 ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
 File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 941, in biff2_8_load
   f = open(filename, open_mode)
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'File_1.xls'
```

Please help me out with the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
No such file or directory: 'File_1.xls'
```

It's *telling* you what the problem is. It can't find the file.

You specify only the filename, so your program is going to look in the current working directory for the file. Usually this is the same directory your Python script is in.

Try specifying the complete path of the file, or else put the Python script in the same directory as the file you're opening.